# Problema executando eventhandler

Tags: c#, sql, .net, eventos, nullpointerexception

Tenho uma classe, que e executada sob de um botão, ela faz dois `select` em um banco. apos, preciso pegar esses dois dados e disponibilizar para usar em um segundo form, estou tentando fazer por `EventHandler`, porem, ao rodar o sistema, ele executa, mas da o erro na linha: `OnDataChange(info);`

> Erro Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto

[image: SS]

Segue código:

```
 public void consulta()
    {
        string sqltring = @"Data Source=tptspo01sql01.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=Tptecnologia;Integrated Security=False;User ID=********Password=*********@;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False";
        string _sql = string.Empty;
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(sqltring);

        string usu, pass;
        int eid, uid;
        usu = textBox1.Text;
        pass = textBox2.Text;

        sqlcon.Open();

            _sql = "SELECT Id_empresa FROM Login WHERE usuario = @usuario AND Passwd = @Passwd";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_sql, sqlcon);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usu;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Passwd", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pass;

            eid = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            _sql = "SELECT Id_usu FROM Login WHERE usuario = @usuario AND Passwd = @Passwd";

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(_sql, sqlcon);

            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usu;
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Passwd", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pass;                

            uid = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();

        sqlcon.Close();

        Hashtable info = new Hashtable();
        info.Add("eid1", Convert.ToString(eid));
        info.Add("uid1", Convert.ToString(uid));
        OnDataChange(info);

        Tinicial frm2 = new Tinicial();

        frm2.Show();

    }
```

Comment: Em qual linha ocorre o erro? O número eu vi, preciso indicação de qual é, já que aí não tem.

Comment: Amigo boa noite, apos a linha : info.Add("uid1", Convert.ToString(uid));, aonde eu chamo OnDataChange(info). nesta linha.

Comment: Não consigo ver um erro aí não. Vejo uma bela gambiarra, mas deveria funcionar. Pelo menos esse erro, neste lugar, não deveria acontecer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiro problema: não use `HashTable`, esta classe é obsoleta e problemática. Prefira [`Dictionary<string, string>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0), ou quem sabe `Dictionary<string, int>`. Tem certeza que precisa disso? Parece uma gambiarra, mas posso estar enganado. Com valores inteiros pode usar `eid.ToString()`, é mais simples.

Eu não vi outros problemas no local específico. Será que está usando outras coisas não recomendadas?

Na linha mencionada não tem como dar um erro, porque mesmo que o erro fosse dentro do método `OnDataChange`, daria por causa do `info` ser nulo, o que não é o caso. O que pode acontecer é que este `info` não poderia ser um `HashTable` com estes dados. Provavelmente acontece em outro lugar.

O código tem outras coisas que poderiam ser bem melhores, mas vou me limitar ao relatado.

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pelos comentários e vou tentar utilizar esse Dictionary. estou começando a me aventurar em c#, então desculpe pelos erros. Na verdade, estou tentando disponibilizar o "uid" e o "eid" no form2, teria alguma sugestão?